# Hidden Field Value in JavaScript is not posted

Tags: javascript, html, forms, hidden-field

this error is (again) discussed a thousand times in different forums, but I don't find anything that would help me with my problem. I have a form, a hidden field and some links, that change the value of this field and submit the form. I checked it many times.

- the function is called.
- the ID is transferred to the function.
- the hidden field can be accessed.
- the value of the hidden field can be changed.
- the called site has no value from the hidden field.
- if I use a submit-button instead with an `onclick="DeleteEvent(someValue)"` the value is transferred over to the called site... so it IS the hidden field...

somehow... someone an idea what it could be?
Submit works, a href not...
Or could it be the problem of the div?

sourcecode:

```js
function DeleteEvent(id){
  var hiddenId = document.getElementById('hiddenIdField');
  hiddenId.value = id;
  document.forms['deleteForm'].submit();
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" name="deleteForm">
  <input type="hidden" id="hiddenIdField" name="hiddenField" value="testy" />
  <div style="display: none" id="divText18">
    <br />
    <a href="" onclick="DeleteEvent(18)">
      <img src="images/delete.jpg"/>
    </a>
  </div>
<!-- 
  this is the working part:
  <input type="submit" onclick="DeleteEvent(18)" /> 
-->
</form>
```

Comment: did you try using jquery like this for form submit  **$('form#formid').submit()**

Comment: Yes. No change. The function is called, the form is submitted, the value is missing.

Comment: On click of unexisting image in invisible div do smth? Could you provide a testable example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form not working because of active link event. 
Use `event.preventDefault()` for `onclick` events. 
To parse event in your function you need to send it to your function.

```
<form action="" method="post" name="deleteForm">
  <input type="hidden" id="hiddenIdField" name="hiddenField" value="testy" />
  <div style="display: none" id="divText18">
    <br />
    <a href="" onclick="DeleteEvent(18,event)">
      <img src="images/delete.jpg"/>
    </a>
  </div>
<!-- 
  this is the working part:
  <input type="submit" onclick="DeleteEvent(18)" /> 
-->
</form>
```

---

```
function DeleteEvent(id,event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var hiddenId = document.getElementById('hiddenIdField');
  hiddenId.value = id;
  document.forms['deleteForm'].submit();
}
```

Comment: I also had the function inside a jquery $.function()... now without it AND with the preventdefault, it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Prooblem in this code is link tag before image, it sends browser to nowhere on click before submit, so submit can't worki. Just give onclick event to image or give "javascript:;" as href to keep browser on page.

```js
function DeleteEvent(id){
  var hiddenId = document.getElementById('hiddenIdField');
  hiddenId.value = id;
  document.getElementById("deleteForm").submit();
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="POST" id="deleteForm">
  <input type="text" id="hiddenIdField" name="hiddenField" value="testy" />
</form>
<div style="display: inline" id="divText18">
    <img src="images/delete.jpg" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="DeleteEvent(18)" />
</div>
```

but if you have to use it with href, make it stay on page like

```html
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="DeleteEvent(18)">
  <img src="images/delete.jpg />
</a>
```